# Can we use other path intead of usr/bin?

Tags: ftp, script

Im using wallpaper script in my site and it need ImageMagic or Gdlibrary to be installed on server.Server path should be usr/bin/imagemagic or usr/bin/gdlibrary. those scripts must be intalled by server administration but when i informed them they say currently they do not install other scripts/softwares on the server! Now i want to know is there any way to install without using usr/bin path. Is there any way to intall it myself i have access to ftp but there's no path called usr/bin..please help me! Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a web host?  Consider an [alternative](http://www.servwise.com) if so, as there are many applications that require either gd or imagick, and so it should be installed.

To install gd yourself into a different folder, you would need to compile it on the server, and that would require (it is possible to do it without but very hard) shell access.  If your hosts are willing to give you ssh access, they probably do not permit compilation access.

If the wallpaper app is php, you'd also need the relevant php libraries installed.

A workaround might be to do the image processing on a different server and upload.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about GD Library, but: ImageMagick is a suite of tools, and the most prominently used aspect of it is usually found at `/usr/bin/convert` — there is no binary called `imagemagic` that i know of. Try checking that path first.

If it's not there, compiling ImageMagick is relatively simple if you have SSH access:

1. `ssh youruserid@yourhost`
2. `wget ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.tar.gz`
3. `tar zxvf ImageMagick.tar.gz`
4. `cd ImageMagick-6.7.3-1`
5. `./configure --prefix=$HOME/local`
6. `make`
7. `make install`